# Can you use a function as the default argument of another function in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, arguments, default-value

Can I use a function as the default value of an argument in another function? In the example below, I'm trying to use the Wordpress function `get_the_title()` as the default value:

```
function GetPageDepartment($department = get_the_title()) {
    return $department;
}
```

As is, the parentheses are causing a parse error. Is there a way around this, or would I have to pass the function value to a variable somewhere outside of the default values?

*I know the actual code here would be largely pointless as it just returns `get_the_title()`, but it's just as an example, as what I actually do with the argument isn't that relevant to the question.*

Comment: As long as the function is called within the Loop, you can use `get_the_title()` within your function, without passing it as an argument.

Comment: @mevius: So I can! That effectively solves my actual problem, but I'll leave the question up as I'm curious about the answer in PHP exclusive of WordPress. Thanks!

Comment: btw: you already mentioned that it's only an example, but: Your GETSomething function PRINTS something.

Comment: @VolkerK, yeah, final version wouldn't do that, but I'll edit to return it instead. Thanks.

Comment: nah, just nitpicking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no and yes, but ... yet...".
No, using PHP 5.6 you can't assign a function as a default value of a function/method.
Yes, you can assign a string and if you use that parameter/variable in a function context, i.e. `echo $department();`, the string will be treated as the name of a function and `get_the_title()` will be invoked. But... it's kinda ugly that you have to rely on the string->function name relation. Yet ... who cares?

---

edit: for your consideration....

```
<?php
function get_the_title() { return "the title"; }

function GetPageDepartment( callable $department=null ) {
    if ( null==$department ) {
        $department = 'get_the_title';
    }
    return '<'.$department().'>';
}


echo GetPageDepartment();
```

Comment: I care, @VolkerK. I care.

Comment: I see... so you want a little bit more strictness.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't 
use this code

```
<?php

function get_the_title(){
    return 'this is the title';
}
$temp = get_the_title();
function GetPageDepartment($department) {
    echo $department;
}

GetPageDepartment($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I plumped for:

```
function GetPageDepartment($department = null) {
    $department = $department ?: get_the_title(); //Sets value if null.
}
```

which sets the value of $department to get_the_title() if no other value's set.